# how to check which button is being clicked

Tags: javascript

My question is little weird as i have two html `buttons`
as

```
<button>ok</button>
<button>ok</button>
```

and i am attaching `onclick` events on them like this

```
var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(var i=0;i < buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].onclick = function() {  
      focus = this;
      alert("ok i am clicked")
  }
}
```

now after this i am doing

now i have an event attach on `window` as

```
window.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target == focus)
}
```

according to me this `console.log(e.target == focus)` condition should be `true` if i click on `first` button but its also `true` for `second` button!

please tell me where i am wrong and please give `vanilla JavaScript` solution and in my scenario i can't use `id` i am will br very thankful to you :)

[here](http://jsbin.com/quxalejemi/edit?html,js,output) is its bin.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Copying your code prints *true* for the first button and *false* for the second (as expected).

Comment: `for(var i=0;i > buttons.length; i++)` you need change `>` to `<`,of course,it has no matter with your question,and it works as your wish in Chrome

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rktt2ryv/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Why you did not try it in Jquery?. OR Create a variable and then using On Click event, store true value to the variable if the first button is clicked. And  false value for second button @maq

Comment: @RobG @Sky Fang @Arun P Johny sorry i was out kindly check updated question now its always showing `true`

Comment: @MdAslam i hate jquery :/

Comment: Then it's pretty easy to understand your problem : you set the `focus` element on click, then the window listener fires and checks if the target (the button) is the `focus` element. Obviously, it will always be true, since you just set it to be the `focus` element. You could add the window listener with [`target.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and set the `useCapture` to true. Then it will fire before the button's `onclick`, and you'll have to click twice for your callback returns true.

Comment: @Kaiido u r rock please give it as answer so i can accept it as my answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the edit, the solution to your problem is quite simple :

You set the `focus` element on click of each button, then the window listener fires and checks if the target (the button) is the `focus` element.

Obviously, it will always be true, since you just set it to be the `focus` element.

You could add the window listener with [`target.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and set the `useCapture` to `true`.
Then it will fire before the button's onclick, and you'll have to click twice for your callback returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ["**Immediately-invoked function expression**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

This pattern will ensure that during the time of the click `i` will still hold the correct value as it has its own scope:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function () {
            alert("button " + i + " was clicked");
        }
    }(i));
}
```

See the <kbd>[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x697pymu/)</kbd>

Comment: i did nt understand ur answer and i want to check this condition in `window.onload`

Comment: You should explain why your answer fixes the OP's issue. It doesn't (and there's a typo in the code: `i > buttons.length`).

Comment: Thanks RobG - to fast copy paste ;)

Comment: The question is "how to check which button is being clicked"

Comment: and the actual code OP is using for that is `window.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target == focus)
}` no loop there.

Comment: see his first example and you will find a loop.. and maybe the op might add some more info as everyone seems to be confused :D

Comment: yeah I agree, no link with his problem

Comment: @Kaiido is rite i updated my question i want to create hide on click any where implementation in pure JS